# In XCode 5 and iOS 7 push view controller in ViewDidLoad does not working

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, xcode5, xcode5.0.1

Hi I am trying to push a view controller in viewDidLoad

I am using storyboard.
In ViewDidLoad, I am checking that user is login and he is created his profile.
if user is not logged in or he does not created his profile then pushing the another view controller for login/profile view.
The following code does not working.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad

if(USER_IS_LOGGED_IN)
{
    if(USER_PROFILE_COMPLETED)
    {
       [self sendRequest];
    }
    else
    {
        //push profile view      
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        ProfileViewController *profileViewController = (ProfileViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ProfileView"];
        profileViewController.isFromDealView = YES;
        profileViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:profileViewController animated:YES];
    }

    }
    else
    {

    //push login view
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    LoginViewController *loginViewController = (LoginViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginView"];
    loginViewController.isFromDealView = YES;
    loginViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:loginViewController animated:YES];


    }

}
```

Comment: put break point and check it. The push operation compiled or not

Comment: Why doesn't work? Any error, have you check that your navigationController and views are not nil?

Comment: @AshwinDamji:Check in appDelegate are you set rootViewController as NavigationController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't you create the segue from your viewController to the Login and Profile View Controller and use performSegueUsingIdentifier: and push the navigation Controller using  prepareForSegue: method

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad 
   {
    if(USER_IS_LOGGED_IN)
    {
        if(USER_PROFILE_COMPLETED)
        {
           [self sendRequest];
        }
        else
        {
            //push profile view      

            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"profileSegue" sender:self] ;
        }
        }
        else
        {
           //push login view
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loginSegue" sender:self] ;
        }
    }
```

in prepareforsegue method

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {


    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"profileSegue"]) {
      ProfileViewController *profileViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
      profileViewController.isFromDealView = YES;
      profileViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
}
else if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"loginSegue"]){

    LoginViewController *loginViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    loginViewController.isFromDealView = YES;
    loginViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
}
else{
//no segue to push
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am little confuse with your code but any way try this

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {

 if(USER_IS_LOGGED_IN) {
    if(USER_PROFILE_COMPLETED)
    {
       [self sendRequest];
    }
    else
    {
        //push profile view      
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        ProfileViewController *profileViewController = (ProfileViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ProfileView"];
        profileViewController.isFromDealView = YES;
        profileViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:profileViewController animated:YES];
    }
 } else {

    //push login view
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    LoginViewController *loginViewController = (LoginViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginView"];
    loginViewController.isFromDealView = YES;
    loginViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:loginViewController animated:YES];


    }`
 }
```